# PHP pdo_odbc query fails on Windows

Tags: php, pdo, odbc

Please bear with me.. I am not entirely sure how to ask this question. I hope someone catches on.

I do my PHP (7.4 and 8.0) programming in FreeBSD, connecting to Windows based SQL servers using PDO_ODBC. In FreeBSD, I successfully use FreeTDS to pull data over ODBC and everything works.

What I am developing is meant to run on XAMPP or WAMP (or any similar stack) on a Windows Server of recent flavor, but when I copy the PHP code over, my query fails. I have set up a 64bit DSN which successfully connects to the target database and I can run queries against the database - at least in simple terms. The code I am trying to migrate contains a fairly complex query and running it on this platform return 0 data to the PDO. It runs fine in SQL Management Studio.

So the question is very open ended, but for now: Why or what?

Comment: guild guess: dos2unix, unix2dos?

Comment: unix2dos was a good suggestion, but to no avail.

Comment: Curious to know if you found a solution?

Comment: I did not.. Not that I tried all too hard. I ended up building a FreeBSD image for Raspberry Pi 4+ and turned the whole thing into a more-or-less-plug-and-play web server. For my purpose, the Pi is plenty sufficient.